# Creating schema fields GUI extension

Tags: gui-extensions, 2011-sp1

all!

I am developing a GUI extension for schema creation which adds a check box depending on which schema field type is added. This should apply only to normal text fields and rich text fields, but not if "values selected from a list" is selected (either hard-coded values in schema or categories).

Is there any way to distinguish between normal text fields and values selected from a list fields? Code example would be highly appreciated.

Version of Tridion is 2011 SP1.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, that you are adding a check box to the Schema editing screen - next to the existing options? And now you want to hide it unless the user has selected a text field that isn't a list?

Comment: Hi, Peter! Your assumption is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I've never done this before, but my suggestion would be to hook into the 'change' event on the FieldBuilder and then check the status of the relevant input controls. It's also possible that the FieldBuilder exposes information on the type of field the user is currently editing.

If that doesn't work, you could always hook into the 'click' or 'change' events for the related input fields.

You'll have to experiment a bit to find the right solution, but it should definitely be doable to only show your extension controls for certain field types.